# Python error when trying to run K-Means

Tags: python, k-means

I'm attempting to write the K-means algorithm and I thought I was done, so I began to test and it gave me the error:

```
File "kmeans.py", line 112, in update_clusters
    if(data[i].get_cluster() is None or data[i].get_cluster() != currrentCluster):
NameError: global name 'currrentCluster' is not defined
```

Here is my code for my update_clusters definition:

```
def update_clusters():
    isStillMoving = 0

    for i in range(total_data):
        bestmin = big_num
        currentCluster = 0

        for j in range(nclusters):
            distance = get_dist(data[i].get_x(), data[i].get_y(), centroids[j].get_x(), centroids[j].get_y())
            if(distance < bestmin):
                bestmin = distance
                currentCluster = j
        data[i].set_cluster(currentCluster)

        if(data[i].get_cluster() is None or data[i].get_cluster() != currrentCluster):
            data[i].set_cluster(currentCluster)
            isStillMoving = 1

    return isStillMoving
```

I'm not sure why it is unable to recognize currentCluster when I define it right at the beginning. Any help would be great.

Comment: currrentCluster has 3 r

Comment: thank you. I knew it was something simple